# Print Instance of Class In Python as Built-In DataType?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading DiveIntoPython.

I'm wondering why I can directly print the instance of a UserDict as a dictionary.
In detail, these codes

```
import UserDict;

d = UserDict.UserDict({1:1, 'a':2});
print d;
print d.data;
```

will have output

```
{'a': 2, 1: 1}
{'a': 2, 1: 1}
```

And these codes

```
class MyDict:
    def __init__(self, dictData=None):
        self.data = dictData;

d = MyDict({1:1, 'a':2});
print d;
print d.data;
```

will have output (on my machine)

```
<__main__.MyDict instance at 0x10049ef80>
{'a': 2, 1: 1}
```

In other words, How I can define my class, and print its instances as a built-in datatype?
Thank you!

Comment: As a side note -- I don't think too many python programmers enjoy looking at the semicolons at the end of the line.  You can make the "They don't hurt" argument -- **And you'd be absolutely right** (until your co-worker gets tired enough of looking at them that he comes and punches you in the face) -- :-P

Comment: @mgilson Actually, I am also struggling on whether semicolons should be used. What is the motivation of not using it?  Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I was primarily writing C before learning python now, that is the reason that I use semicolons....

Comment: They're unnecessary.  Python's a very elegant language and I think that a lot of people would argue that it visually disrupts the flow of thought as you try to read the code.  And, C and languages which are influenced by it are the reason most people use semicolons ;-)

Comment: @mgilson Sounds reasonable. I'll think about it. Thank you for pointing it out. :)

Comment: `UserDict` hasn't been relevant for a really, really long time (and is gone in 3.x). You can and should inherit directly from the builtin `dict` instead now. (Leaving aside the question of whether you really want to inherit from a container type...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How an object is printed comes down to it's `repr` - when you inherit from a mixin, it already provides the `repr` function. Also note, these days you can just inherit from `dict` directly.

In your case, you can define

```
def __repr__(self):
    return repr(self.data)
```

The difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` is that mostly `__str__` should be readable and understable. `__repr__` where it's possible can be used to provide an `eval`'d string constructing the original object (although not necessary) - see the great answer here for the difference: [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: actually, `print` implicitly calls `str`, not `repr`.  Of course, for objects which don't define their own `__str__`, `__repr__` is what is called as the fallback ...

Comment: true, but if no `__str__` is defined `__repr__` is fallen back on

Comment: Thank you! But is the purpose of `__repr__` merely for debug?

Comment: @KFC not especially - read the accepted answer on the link I've provided- and that explains it much better than I can!